# Как разделить нецелое число на составные части и перемножить/сложить

Tags: python

У меня есть такая проблема. Пользователь вводит число с клавиатуры (число может быть целое, а может быть дробное). Нужно перемножить цифры, из которых состоит это число. Потом сложить. Результаты вывести в консоль.

Я написала код, но он не работает с дробными числами. Как сделать с дробными числами - ума не приложу. Быть может, нужен список с помощью которого можно бы было  вытаскивать цифры...

Буду благодарна за помощь.

```
vvod = str(input('Введите число: '))
proizvedenie = 1 # ибо умножение на ноль приведет к нулю
summ = 0
for i in vvod:
    proizvedenie *= int(i)
    summ += int(i)


print('Сумма введенных чисел = {s}'.format(s = summ))
print('Произведение введенных чисел = {p}'.format(p = proizvedenie))
```

Comment: сделайте проверку, если символ "." или "," то пропустить его и не умножать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал два варианта, первый с помощью try и except, сначала идёт проверка кода в try, если ошибок не было код выполняется, если была ошибка то выполняется код в except.
Второй вариант - проверка, если символ не равен "." или "," то выполняется умножение и сложение

````
proizvedenie = 1 # ибо умножение на ноль приведет к нулю
summ = 0
for i in vvod:
    try:
        proizvedenie *= int(i)
        summ += int(i)
    except:
        continue
print('Сумма введенных чисел = {s}'.format(s = summ))
print('Произведение введенных чисел = {p}'.format(p = proizvedenie))
proizvedenie = 1 # ибо умножение на ноль приведет к нулю
summ = 0
for i in vvod:
    if i!="," and i!=".":
        proizvedenie *= int(i)
        summ += int(i)
print('Сумма введенных чисел = {s}'.format(s = summ))
print('Произведение введенных чисел = {p}'.format(p = proizvedenie))```
````

Comment: Что-то как-то усложняете

Comment: @Gespover один вариант привел более простой, а второй более универсальный, для обработки всех исключений

Answer (score 0):

Если все правильно понял, то можно перед тем, как перемножать все это дело -- просто добавить проверку

```
for i in vvod:
    if type(i) != int:
        continue
    proizvedenie *= int(i)
    summ += int(i)
```

Comment: _`if i != int:`_ - это какой-то бред... Строка не может быть равна функции. Хотя задумка верная, вроде.

Comment: Забыл type() прописать, тут да, тут дурак.

Comment: Всё равно `vvod` - строка, значит `i` - тоже строка, а значит не int.